# Why protobuf is said to be in binary format although we write it in text format similar to json

Tags: json, protobuf

JSON

```
{
"hello": "world"
}
```

Protobuf

```
message HelloWorld {
required string name = 1;
}
```

Why do we say that protobuf uses binary format during network exchange and json don't, even though network always will transfer using binary data format?

Comment: The question in your title is different than your question in the post. The JSON example you provided is the _message_, while the Protobuf example is the _schema_. You define the schema in a text file, but that doesn't mean the Protobuf message will be sent as text. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks @VincentSavard I was aware that I am putting schema, but I thought data would also be textual for protobuf (wrongly assumed, apologies). I was following logic of xml xsd as both are in text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be more clear if you were comparing two more similar pieces of data with non-text data components.

For example, the following JSON is ALL text:

```
{
    "NumberOfClients": 20
}
```

### The 20 is two separate characters in JSON, but would be represented as an actual binary  integer in Protobuf, which in this case would be a single byte: `‭00010100‬`

Further, I am not sure you are properly understanding Protobuf as you are comparing apples and oranges in your question. You are comparing JSON *Data* to a Protobuf *Schema*

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks for explanation. Though I knew I was putting schema in case of in case of protobuf, I wrongly assumed (apologies) that data would also be same.

Comment: Sounds very much to the all XMLBeans in Java.

Comment: The last paragraph of the answer seems to be the actual answer to the question - that 20 isn't "20" but 00010100 in the protobuf says more about JSON than about protobuf. I feel this answer would be better of that last line where made the main point.

Comment: @JoryGeerts noted, remedy attempted